# Can I prevent superfluous loading of multiple css files?

Tags: html, css

I have 8 css files, sorted into more or less logical groups. I have 25 HTML chapters with formatting, figures, tables, lists, references, indexing, and footnotes, so each chapter starts by calling all 8 css files. This means that a reader can open any chapter and have everything work, but it probably means that multiple copies get loaded. Is there a standard way to prevent superfluous loads?

Comment: How are chapters loaded? Is each chapter it's own HTML file? Can a reader view multiple chapters per load?

Comment: You could minify the files

Answer (score 0):

The browser caches also css files (only load again if changed), so you don't need to worry about it: the browser prevents superfluous loads.

Comment: That's what I needed to know!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like your CSS has any extraordinarily complex code in there.

I would suggest **combining all of them into one `main.css` file** - given that there's no overwrite that occurs - for example if `h1` looks different in every chapter

Then loading the combined `main.css` file on **every page**.

With the **right caching headers**, The file will be downloaded when the visitor opens any of your pages **for the first time** but it will **not need to be downloaded again** on the other pages, it will be **served from the user's browser cache instead**